# Adding Xcode Github Account via CLI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, continuous-integration, bitrise

I'm attempting to build my iOS app on bitrise.io. This app uses an SPM package which is hosted in a private github repo. The repo is not able to be made public.

Locally the builds work, they also work locally with fastlane and the bitrise cli. When I run them on the remote pipeline, I get the following error:

```
xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:
  Failed to clone repository https://github.com/USERNAME_REDACTED/REPO_NAME_REDACTED:
    Cloning into bare repository '/Users/vagrant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ORG_NAME_REDACTED/SourcePackages/repositories/REPO_NAME_REDACTED-d35b1ef7'...
    fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

My understanding as to why this does not work, is because the Xcode instance on the remote pipeline machine, does not have a GitHub account added. I am able to do this using the Xcode GUI locally by going to `Xcode > Preferences > Accounts` as you can see below

[image: Xcode Add Account]

The problem here is that I need to figure out a way to do this via script for the remote by providing a username and personal access token. Thus far I've spent about 20 hours looking through `xcodebuild` docs and messing around with different configs however I've not had any luck getting this to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ask not what Xcode can do for you.  Ask what you can do for oAuth like OAuthSwift and p2.OAuth2.

Comment: What would either of those libraries achieve here? They would allow a swift app to authenticate with GitHub which is not what the question is asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Xcode project to use ssh to import the module worked for this. I had to also change the remote CI machine to use the system keychain in order to fetch the SSH key.